# Laravel hasMany relation on multiple columns

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to setup Laravel relations on an already existing database which I'm unable to change.

In this database there is a table named `Teams` with columns:

- Teamleader_1
- Teamleader_2

Furthermore there's a table named `Users` with a column:

- User_id

The relation between these tables is as follows: `Users.User_id` = `Teams.Teamleader_1` OR `Users.User_id` = `Teams.Teamleader 2`

How can I setup a hasMany relationship between Users and Teams on both teamleader columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to define 2 relations in your team model:

```
public function teamleader1() {
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'Teamleader_1', 'User_id');
}

public function teamleader2() {
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'Teamleader_2', 'User_id');
}
```

Once you have it, define an accessor that will get the teamleader from either of those relations:

```
public function getTeamleaderAttribute() {
  return $this->teamleader1 ?: $this->teamleader2;
}
```

Once you have it, you should be able to access the user by calling:

```
$teamLeader = $team->teamleader;
```